# Repeatedly getting an error as `Type Mismatch` in the VBScript code

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Could you please tell me what's wrong with the below part of the code? repeatedly getting an error as `Type Mismatch` in the below code:

```
    TotalRows=objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob4.Columns(1))
'MsgBox(TotalRows)
ReDim ArrParent(TotalRows - 2)
ArrParent=ob4.Range("A2:" & "A" & TotalRows).Value 'here i am getting an error as said above
'Call to the subroutine
ParentPIDNumber ArrParent,ob3,ob2,ob4
```

**CODE**

```
    Sub FileredOpenProcessToDel(ob3,ob2,ob4)

        Dim ColumnToFilter,TotalRows
        Dim rngFilter,cel,str,rangesToRemove,x 
        Dim strToRemove : strToRemove = ""
        Dim ArrParent

        objExcel1.ScreenUpdating = False
        objExcel1.Calculation = -4135  'xlCalculationManual
        ColumnToFilter=objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob4.Rows(1)) - 1
        ob4.Range(ob4.Cells(1,ColumnToFilter),ob4.Cells(1,ColumnToFilter)).AutoFilter ColumnToFilter, "Open",,,True 

        'Dim rngFilter as Range
        Set rngFilter = objExcel1.Application.Intersect(ob4.UsedRange,ob4.UsedRange.Offset(1),ob4.Columns(1)).SpecialCells(12)'xlCellTypeVisible
           'MsgBox(rngFilter.Rows.Count)
           REM Do While 1=1
            REM 'Msgbox
           REM Loop
        'msgbox "Filtered range has " & rngFilter.Rows.Count & " rows."
            str=""
            For each cel in rngFilter

              str = str & (cel.row) & ":" & (cel.row) & "," 

            Next

                    rangesToRemove = Split(str,",")

                    For x = UBOUND(rangesToRemove)-1 To LBOUND(rangesToRemove) Step -1

                         strToRemove = strToRemove & rangesToRemove(x)

                            If Len(strToRemove) > 200 then

                                ob4.Range(strToRemove).delete'str & rangesToRemove(x) & ":" & rangesToRemove(x) & ","
                                strToRemove = ""

                            Else

                                strToRemove = strToRemove & ","

                            End If

                    Next
                    If len(strToRemove) > 0 then

                        strToRemove = Mid(strToRemove, 1, Len(strToRemove) - 1)
                        'strToRemove = Left(strToRemove, Len(strToRemove) -1)
                        ob4.Range(strToRemove).delete

                    End If

        ob4.AutoFilterMode = False
        objExcel1.ScreenUpdating = True
        objExcel1.Calculation = -4105   'xlCalculationAutomatic

        TotalRows=objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob4.Columns(1))
        MsgBox(TotalRows)
        'ReDim ArrParent(TotalRows - 2)
        ArrParent=ob4.Range("A2:A" & TotalRows).value2
        'MsgBox(ArrParent(1,0))
        'Call to the subroutine
        ParentPIDNumber ArrParent,ob3,ob2,ob4

    End Sub
```

[image: Screen]

Thanks,

Comment: what value gets assigned to TotalRows?

Comment: @SamWard `totalrows` is the number of data in the column#1. please help me here,i really stuck here!

Comment: i mean before the error occurs what value is TotalRows? Can you add a breakpoint and step through the code or add Msgbox(TotalRows) just before the error.

Comment: Try using Application.Transpose to store the values to a 2d array  ||      ArrParent=Application.Transpose(ob4.Range("A2:A" & TotalRows).value)

Comment: @SamWard thanks for your help! its working now!! :-)

Comment: @SamWard put your comments as your answer,so that i can accept it and give a vote to your help! :-)

Comment: I added it as an answer. I'm glad you managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Application.Transpose to store the values to a 1d array ||

```
ArrParent=Application.Transpose(ob4.Range("A2:A" & TotalRows).value)
```

***Edit***

I believe that a range array is always a two dimensional array. Transpose is used to convert the data to a one dimensional array.

you were initially assigning ArrParent to array(0, 968) instead of what you wanted which was array(968).

I think my explanation is correct. Someone please correct me if I'm not.

Comment: can you tell me the logic behind it?

Comment: Lbound(ArrParent) gives me lower bound as `1`, But why not it is `0`?

Comment: Not sure. I would have expected it to be 0